# Unity - Detect if Game Center is available

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, game-center

My Game is using Unity API to call Game Center and I want to use it like "Archero".

i want to make it possible:

if Game Center is available: login and show banner...etc.

if not: just give me a callback, DO NOT show the Game Center Authenticate Panel.

but no matter how I call the authentication function, it ALWAYS pop the Authenticate panel.

is there any solution to detect if the Game Center is available?

By the way, someones said that when user cancel Authentication 3 times, Game Center will block user.
If i can do that by code will be pretty useful, i can use it to deal with my problems

Here is my Authenticate Code:

```
public void OnClick_Authenticate()
{
try
{
    Social.localUser.Authenticate(ProcessAuthentication);
}
catch
{
    ActiveCallback();
}
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you have written, and where you are struggling

Comment: I just edit the code what i use, but it is the simple Unity API

Comment: When is it not available? Wouldn't it maybe be enough to check internet connectivity on general?

Comment: thanks for your response, but i don't know why i need to check the internet?

Comment: did you find a solution to this one? I'm noticing the same behaviour on archero and I'm really curious to know how they are handling this behaviour!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible/intended. You're talking about the iOS "popup" right?

Like derHugo says, check for internet connectivity is your best option

Comment: Excuse me, why i need to check internet connectivity? i just  want to know if the Game Center in iOS is ON or OFF before authentication. Is there any detail i don't know?

Comment: Maybe try to check if "Social.localUser" exists? I don't see anything in the documentation of Unity where you can check if Game Center is enabled.

Comment: But. In the "Archero", when i already login the Game Center, it will show the banner, if not, there is nothing. i really want to know how do they do that.

Comment: Did you try to check for "Social.localUser"? If Archero does it (and it's build in Unity) then yes – you're right, there has to be a way

Comment: I;m pretty sure that Archero is made by Unity, and i had tried every parameter and function i can get, but there is nothing helpful

Comment: Internet connectivity has nothing to do... The question is about the game center "login" view that suddenly shows up

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you have to create your custom plugin to achieve what Archero is doing.

At the end of the authentication process, iOS returns the viewController with the "login" form if the user is not authenticated.

On iOS the developer can decide to present this viewController or not. The social plugin doesn't have this option, they always present the login viewController if returned by the system... if you implement your plugin you could decide not to show it... ending up with what Archero is doing.